# Windows 8.1 Store Tile does not display update count

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade, windows-store-app, live-tiles

After upgrading one of my laptops with preinstalled Windows 8 to 8.1 in November 2013, I detected that the Store tile on the Start screen has never displayed update count. I do not have a lot of 3rd-party installed Metro apps on that pc, but as I remember, this tile indicated 1-2 available updates at least every two weeks when I was working with Windows 8 all the previous year.

What can be wrong?

FYI:

1. I am logged in to my WinLive account on this pc and in the Store App as well.
2. The 'Live tile' setting is on for the Store tile. But AFAIK, even if I set this off, I can see the updates when I open the Store app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8.1 auto-updates apps by default, so there wouldn't be any update notifications. You can disable this from Settings in the Windows Store app.

Comment: I have just turned the Automatic Update off (Settings->App Update). And really, the Store tile has displayed 1 update available immediately! I checked for updates manually in the same settings section, and I really have one update available for the Maps app.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to duplicate this behavior by going to Settings -> Tiles and clicking Clear personal info from tiles from the 'Start' screen. After doing that the number of updates does not show up on the Start screen.

To reverse this, in the store app go to Permissions and toggle Notifications off and then back on.  On my 8.1 machine this re-enabled the update number being displayed on the Start screen.

Comment: This did not help. Have not seen any updated count on the tile for the last 3 days.

Comment: Being that you upgraded, this may be a bug or issue with the way the application behaves after the upgrade process.  I've not been able to duplicate this issue on an 8.1 VM or an 8.0 machine.  I have not tested upgrading the 8.0 machine yet so I cannot be sure.